# Command to replace data in the nth column if the line begins with pattern

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like below:

```
16815966|Mr|Fit 5|Dont Usee|15-07-2015|||||||||||||0|2|0|0.00|0|  
21875307|Mr|Father|Dont Remove|X|31-12-1899|||||||||||||0|118|0|0.00|0|
19180802|Mr|Dontye|Harr|01-01-1900|||||6666|Avenue||||||06-09-2013|0|26|2|396.00|1|
```

I Want to replace 4th column value with blank if begins with "Dont" and pattern like Dont Remove, Dont Use. But if its like one in 3rd example i wanna retain it.

Desired Result:

```
16815966|Mr|Fit 5||15-07-2015|||||||||||||0|2|0|0.00|0|  
21875307|Mr|Father||X|31-12-1899|||||||||||||0|118|0|0.00|0|
19180802|Mr|Dontye|Harr|01-01-1900|||||6666|Avenue||||||06-09-2013|0|26|2|396.00|1|
```

Tried below and one with awk but no luck!!
`sed '/^Dont/s/[^|]*//4'`.

Comment: You should just use the correct awk.  Hint `$4 ~ /^Dont/` may play a role.

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F"|" '$4~/^Dont/{$4=""} 1' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
16815966|Mr|Fit 5||15-07-2015|||||||||||||0|2|0|0.00|0|
21875307|Mr|Father||X|31-12-1899|||||||||||||0|118|0|0.00|0|
```

Comment: How about matching `(Dd)on't`, ie proper English? Perhaps `'$4~/^[dD]on'"'"'?t/{$4=""} 1'` ?  `;-)`

Comment: In addition i wanted to retain the value if its like one in sample 3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for **PHP**.

**Regex**: `(?m)^(?:[\w ]+\|){3}\K(?:(Dont))(?(1)[^\|]+)` **Substitution**: `""` empty string.

```
$text = '16815966|Mr|Fit 5|Dont Usee|15-07-2015|||||||||||||0|2|0|0.00|0|  
         21875307|Mr|Father|Dont Remove|X|31-12-1899|||||||||||||0|118|0|0.00|0|
         19180802|Mr|Dontye|Harr|01-01-1900|||||6666|Avenue||||||06-09-2013|0|26|2|396.00|1|';

$text = preg_replace('/(?m)^(?:[\w ]+\|){3}\K(?:(Dont))(?(1)[^\|]+)/', "",$text);
print_r($text);
```

**Output**:

```
16815966|Mr|Fit 5||15-07-2015|||||||||||||0|2|0|0.00|0|  
21875307|Mr|Father||X|31-12-1899|||||||||||||0|118|0|0.00|0|
19180802|Mr|Dontye|Harr|01-01-1900|||||6666|Avenue||||||06-09-2013|0|26|2|396.00|1|
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mbxHy/2)